# Calculate time between now and a specific timepoint

Tags: python, time, sleep

I am trying to make a program in python that starts doing a task at a specific time every day. Because it will run forever when the pc is on I want to make it as light as I can. So instead of checking the time forever, I would like to check the time once and calculate how many seconds to sleep until the right time.

Comment: If on a *nix system, perhaps consider scheduling the task as a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

whatever mechansim you choose to alert you and run the script is up to you but in terms of calculating time you can use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).  So for example;

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
tomorrow = now + timedelta(1)
```

So you can imagine now, all you'd have to do is convert the result to whatever format you want. (seconds, minutes, hours, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
import time

startTime = time.time()
time.sleep(3600) # one hour from current time
if time.time() - startTime > 3600:
 yourTask()
```

OR

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
currTime = datetime.now()
futureTime = currTime+timedelta(hours = 2) # 2 hours from now, you also can specify days
time.sleep(futureTime-currTime)
#OR Just
time.sleep(timedelta(hours = 2))
yourTask()
```

That's the general idea of sleep and time function in python

Answer (score 0):

To run the same function at the same time every day you can use the `sched.scheduler` class below or a solution that does not require that class, which I show afterwards and is somewhat simpler:

See the documentation for the Python Event Scheduler module [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) (in part):

*class* sched.`scheduler`(timefunc=time.monotonic, delayfunc=time.sleep)

> The scheduler class defines a generic interface to scheduling events. It needs two functions to actually deal with the “outside world” — timefunc should be callable without arguments, and return a number (the “time”, in any units whatsoever). The delayfunc function should be callable with one argument, compatible with the output of timefunc, and should delay that many time units. delayfunc will also be called with the argument 0 after each event is run to allow other threads an opportunity to run in multi-threaded applications.

scheduler.`enterabs`(time, priority, action, argument=(), kwargs={})

> Schedule a new event. The time argument should be a numeric type compatible with the return value of the timefunc function passed to the constructor. Events scheduled for the same time will be executed in the order of their priority. A lower number represents a higher priority.

```python
import datetime
import sched
import time

# number of seconds in:
HOURS_SECONDS = 3600
MINUTES_SECONDS = 60

def my_time_func():
    date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    # convert time component to absolute seconds since midnight:
    return date_and_time.hour * HOURS_SECONDS + date_and_time.minute * MINUTES_SECONDS  + date_and_time.second

def my_sleep_func(t):
    #print('sleeping', t, 'seconds')
    time.sleep(t)

def do_work():
    print('I am working!')

s = sched.scheduler(timefunc=my_time_func, delayfunc=my_sleep_func)
# schedule something to begin every day at (24-hour clock:)
EVENT_HOURS=9
EVENT_MINUTES=35
EVENT_SECONDS=0
first_time = True
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    next_event_dt = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour=EVENT_HOURS, minute=EVENT_MINUTES, second=EVENT_SECONDS)
    schedule_event = True
    if first_time:
        first_time = False
        # maybe too late for initial schedule day:
        if next_event_dt < now:
            schedule_event = False
    if schedule_event:
        event = s.enterabs(time=EVENT_HOURS * HOURS_SECONDS + EVENT_MINUTES * MINUTES_SECONDS + EVENT_SECONDS, priority=1, action=do_work)
        s.run()
    delta = next_event_dt + datetime.timedelta(days=1) - datetime.datetime.now()
    my_sleep_func(delta.total_seconds())
```

And if you do not want to use the `sched.scheduler` class:

```python
import datetime
import time

# number of seconds in:
HOURS_SECONDS = 3600
MINUTES_SECONDS = 60

def my_sleep_func(t):
    #print('sleeping', t, 'seconds')
    time.sleep(t)

def do_work():
    print('I am working!')

# schedule something to begin every day at (24-hour clock:)
EVENT_HOURS=10
EVENT_MINUTES=30
EVENT_SECONDS=0
first_time = True
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    next_event_dt = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour=EVENT_HOURS, minute=EVENT_MINUTES, second=EVENT_SECONDS)
    schedule_event = True
    if first_time:
        first_time = False
        # maybe too late for initial schedule day:
        if next_event_dt < now:
            schedule_event = False
    if schedule_event:
        delta = next_event_dt - datetime.datetime.now()
        t = delta.total_seconds()
        if t > 0:
            my_sleep_func(t)
        do_work()
    delta = next_event_dt + datetime.timedelta(days=1) - datetime.datetime.now()
    my_sleep_func(delta.total_seconds())
```

If you want to make sure that you work function runs on the initial day even if your program starts after the starting time for the event, then change your loop to the following (a similar change can be made if you are using the `sched.scheduler` class):

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    next_event_dt = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour=EVENT_HOURS, minute=EVENT_MINUTES, second=EVENT_SECONDS)
    delta = next_event_dt - datetime.datetime.now()
    t = delta.total_seconds()
    if t > 0:
        my_sleep_func(t)
    do_work()
    delta = next_event_dt + datetime.timedelta(days=1) - datetime.datetime.now()
    my_sleep_func(delta.total_seconds())
```

Needless to say (but I will say it anyway), `my_sleep_func` is just a `time.sleep` replacement with the ability to print out some diagnostics if you uncomment out the `print` statement.